# Not able to Get data from multiple independent tables that have a common column and yet do not depend on each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 8 tables all with equal number of columns and with a common column. I want to fetch data from all tables in a single query.

My table structure is TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3, ..... TABLE 8. 
that have columns  COLUMNA, COLUMNB... COLUMNE and a COMMON_COLUMN
I need to get data with a where clause where COMMON_COLUMN='X'

I will need all columns from all tables.

I used a query that goes like this..

```
    SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.*, TABLE3.*

    FROM TABLE1 T1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COMMON_COLUMN = T2.COMMON_COLUMN,
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T1.COMMON_COLUMN = T3.COMMON_COLUMN

    WHERE T1.COMMON_COLUMN='X' AND T2.COMMON_COLUMN='X' AND  T3.COMMON_COLUMN='X'
```

The above query is not giving any results even if one of the tables do not have any rows. I do not want to use inner join because although the tables have a common column they do not depend on each other and I need data from all tables with a certain common column.

Also, the tables have unequal number of rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add some sample data to your question.

Comment: Agreed with Tim. I deleted my answer after I saw your comment on his answer saying that some tables will have multiple records with the same `COMMON_COLUMN` value. What does the expected result set look like in that case?

Comment: Working on adding some data. Thanks for trying to answer ... :)

Comment: Maybe you want a `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`), that is instead of combining the tables' rows "from left to right", combine them "from top to bottom"? Sounds more reasonable to me here.

Comment: wild guess: you're using `LEFT JOIN` but you're checking `COMMON_COLUMN = 'X'` on ALL tables, which means if there's only one table that doesn't match with another, that record won't show on the results. You need to check your `WHERE` condition only on your "main" table; the `JOIN`s will do the rest

Answer (score 0):

correct me if i am wrong - as you do not attach any sample data and desired result
but i assume that you simply need union all tables. You write in the title that tables are independent

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE T1.COMMON_COLUMN='X'

UNION ALL

SELECT T2.*
FROM TABLE2 T2
WHERE T2.COMMON_COLUMN='X'

UNION ALL

SELECT T3.*
FROM TABLE3 T3
WHERE T3.COMMON_COLUMN='X'

...
```